# How to replace b tag with @ sign

Tags: php

I have a string that looks like this

```
  $t="&#60;b&#62;vist&#60;/b&#62;thank you for the follow.";
```

I am trying to remove the tag b and put an "@" instead of this tag.

I tried this

```
 str_replace("<b></b>","@",$t);
```

but it doesn't replace the closing tag.

I don't know why it is not working may be there is something omitted in the code.

Comment: Could you specifiy your question a little more? I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace multiple words using str_replace() function,

You can Try this

```
 $t="<b>vist</b> thank you for the follow"; 

$pattern=array();
$pattern[0]="<b>";
$pattern[1]="</b>"; 
$replacement=array();
$replacement[0]="@";
$replacement[1]="";
echo str_replace($pattern,$replacement,$t);
```

View the [Demo](https://eval.in/316862)

Comment: You could to the code way shorter: `$pattern=array("<b>","</b>");` and `$replacement=array("@", "");`

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
$search = array('&#60b&#62','&#60/b&#62');
 $replace = '@';
 echo str_replace($search, $replace, $t);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
$t="&#60b&#62vist&#60/b&#62";
echo str_replace(array("&#60b&#62", "&#60/b&#62"),"@",$t);
```

Comment: Looks like ' thank you for the follow ' is part of the $t declaration.